# Find the limit of a recursively defined sequence.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

> $$
> F_k=\begin{cases}
> 4G_{k-1},\ k>1\\
> 0,\ k=1
> \end{cases}
> \\
> G_k=\begin{cases}
> 4^{k-1}-2G_{k-1},\ k>1\\
> 1,\ k=1
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   Find
>   $$
> \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{F_k}{4^k}
> $$

Here is what I did: I substituted $F_k$ with $G_k$ in the limit, i.e.
$$
\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{F_k}{4^k}=
\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{G_{k-1}}{4^{k-1}}
$$
But I have no idea how to find such a limit. If anyone could give me some clue, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. If the limit exists and it is equal to $L$ then by letting $k\to \infty$ on both sides we find
$$L\leftarrow\frac{G_k}{4^k}=\frac{4^{k-1}-2G_{k-1}}{4^k}\rightarrow \frac{1}{4}-\frac{L}{2}\implies L=\frac{1}{6}.$$

P.S. Note that the linear recurrence $G_k+2G_{k-1}=4^{k-1}$ with $G_1=1$ can be easily solved: $G_k=A(-2)^k+B4^k$ where $A,B$ are real numbers to be determined.

Comment: Wow, it was a simple trick! Now I see. Thank you!

Comment: @Bonrey Yes now it remains to show that the limit exists. See also my edit.

Comment: But how can I prove that L exists if $\frac{G_k}{4^k}$ is not monotonous and bounded at the same time?

Comment: $a_k=\frac{G_k}{4^k}$ is bounded but not monotone. Consider the subsequence $a_{2k}$ and $a_{2k+1}$. Or see my P.S. and find $G_k$ explicitly.